# Qt: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, qt, linker-errors

I am trying to create a class in Qt but when i do i get the error of

> symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

and i do not understad why this is happening. The compile output is

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "MyThread::MyThread()", referenced from:
>
> Login::on_pushButton_clicked() in login.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

My code is 
Pass.h

```
#ifndef PASS_H
#define PASS_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QThread>
extern int Searching, Account_Type, table;
extern QString query;
extern bool executed;

class Pass
{
public:
    Pass();
};

class MyThread : public QThread
{
public:
    MyThread();
    void run();
};
```

Pass.cpp

```
#include "pass.h"
#include <QtCore>
#include <QDebug>
int Searching, Account_Type, table;
QString query;
bool executed;
Pass::Pass()
{
}

void MyThread::run()
{
    qDebug() << "Hello World";
}
```

and login.cpp where the class is being used

```
if(tries == 10)
    {
        MyThread mThread;
    }
```

if i comment out MyThread mThread out the program opens fine. How can i fix this issue.

Comment: but i have not used any commands to build the executable all i have done is press the green triangle to build

Comment: Where is your definition of `MyThread::MyThread()`?

Comment: the problem is i hav't ever defined mythread::mythred() i even did i spotlight search on my entire HDD and spotlight could not find anything

Comment: the problem is with the line MyThread mThread

Comment: Well, you promised to define one when you declared it in `class MyThread`. If you want to use the default-generated one instead, remove the `MyThread()` declaration from that class, otherwise define one.